# didUpdateLocations stops updating

Tags: swift, swift2, avfoundation, core-location

In my Swift 2.0 app, I'm using CoreLocation to check whether the user is within 1km of a certain place and if they are, I use AVFoundation to play a sound.

The problem is, when I start playing the audio within the didUpdateLocations, it stops updating, even after the audio stops..

Here's my code:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {



    //Method called every time the location is updated by CoreLocation



    let userLocation = locations[0]


    var i = 0

    while i < coordinates.count {

        //Looping through all different coordinates



        let location = CLLocation(coordinate: coordinates[i], altitude: 0, horizontalAccuracy: kCLLocationAccuracyBest, verticalAccuracy: kCLLocationAccuracyBest, timestamp: NSDate())



        if userLocation.distanceFromLocation(location) < 1001 {


            //If the user is within 1000m of area[i]



            if player.rate == 0.0 {

                //Checks for the player already playing something else


                if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(titles[i], withExtension: "mp3") {                            


                        player.removeAllItems()
                        player.insertItem(AVPlayerItem(URL: url), afterItem: nil)
                        player.play()






                        i = 10 //We had an area that was closer and the player is finished, so we stop the loop

                }


            }


        } else {

            //This location was further than 1000 meters, so we up the count and check the next coordinate

            i += 1

        }

    }

}
```

Since the didUpdateLocations just stops updating, I can't play audio when the user enters another area. Your help is highly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What should happen if player.rate != 0.0, or the "if let url" condition is false?

Comment: @DevKyle Nothing should happen. Only if the rate of the player is 0.0 (i.e. it isn't playing anything) and the url is valid, the audio needs to be played. What I find strange is that when the audio starts playing, it seems like CoreLocation just stops working at all.

Comment: Are you obtaining your location with 'requestLocation()` method? This cause that Core Location obtain device location and then stops to update device location

Comment: @Adolfo I obtain the location by using manager.startUpdatingLocations(). When I comment out the audio part, it works fine and updates every second, but when I uncomment it, it only gets called once or twice.

Comment: I asked the question because it looks like your while loop will be stuck if the conditions aren't met because the i-value won't change. I might be wrong, but based on looking at the code that is on this page, that would seem to be the case. Not sure if that helps at all..

Comment: @DevKyle I was thinking about this too, but if I comment out the three player lines, it works fine.. That leads my to thinking it's related to AVFoundation.

Comment: I don't know if this will work or not (or that it even conforms to your design req), but how about remove the three player lines from the loop and call it as a function upon loop exit? So maybe create a function: func player() { 3 player lines}, then call the function immediately following the while loop. If I recall correctly, Xcode waits until the while loop is finished before moving on to the next line of codes.

Comment: Well, I will certainly try this. I already tried a playing the audio in a separate function called by a timer, so completely unrelated to the didUpdateLocations and still, it stopped getting called..

Comment: @DevKyle It was indeed related to the while loop being infinite. If you want to, you can post it as an answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your while loop will be stuck if player.rate != 0.0, or the "if let url" condition is false because the i-value won't change. I might be wrong, but based on looking at the code that is on this page, that would seem to be the case.